# How to open in lightning experience a custom visualforce page that requires parameters?

Tags: visualforce, lightning, lightning-experience, url, parameters

**Scenario:**

I have two custom visualforce pages called, *reportlist* and *reportshow*. The *reportlist* does not accept parameters and opens via an app's tab in salesforce classic. The *reportlist* displays a table and each row has a link that opens the *reportshow* visualforce page with specific parameters (not URL hacks).

Also, *reportshow* uses third-party scripts via static resource and relies on the custom parameters for loading salesforce reports. Without parameters, *reportshow* will return an error.

**Problem:**

When I switch to lightning experience, *reportlist* seems to load fine, but the table links that open *reportshow* ends up displaying the following:

```
URL No Longer Exists
You have attempted to reach a URL that no longer exists on salesforce.com.
```

**Observations:**

I noticed the following difference after trying to open a *reportshow*:

1. The fqdn is different on the error page compared to the url when I hover in the *reportlist*.
2. The path `/apex/` became `/one/`.

[Sample hover link]

https://ns-dev-ed--ns.na30.visual.force.com/apex/reportshow?id=00O36000002TXfdEAG&reportName=TestReport

[Sample URL in address bar of error page]

https://ns-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/one/reportshow?id=00O36000002TXfdEAG&reportName=TestReport

**Attempted fixes:**

I tried prefixing `apex/` to the href value in the *reportlist*, but hovering on the links now displays `/apex/apex/` and clicking it leads me to URL No Longer Exists.

I also tried adding `target="_blank"` and it works as expected minus the lightning experience.

**Question:**

How do I open the *reportshow* visualforce page in lightning experience?

Comment: You may want to check if it's related to namespace - https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008ascAAA

Comment: Thanks @GauravKheterpal, your suggestion and the link in your comment satisfied my question. Would you mind adding it as an answer so I may accept it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks to be a namespace issue similar to the one described [here](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008ascAAA) - currently in review.

It can be reproduced using these steps as mentioned on the link

> - Create an namespace on your Developer Org and a Managed Package
> - Add the two Visualforce Pages to the package and upload it copying the link
> - Log into another organization and install the package.
> - Override the Account View with TestPage1 and then switch to Lightning Experience.
> - Navigate to any Account page and click on either the A href link or OutputLink, clicking OutputLink will work as expected maintaining the
>     correct namespace, clicking on A href link will navigate to your
>     default org namespace which results in either URL "No Longer Exists"
>     or "Page namespace__TestPage1 does not exist". (Behavior varies on how
>     the page will display)

The suggested workaround is not ideal, but it works

> 1) Right click on the link and select "Open Link in New Tab";
>   2)
>   Disable Lightning Experience;
>   3) Change the  tag references to
>   make use of the Visualforce tag

Comment: This answer has solved my problem because it showed me about using the managed <apex:outputLink> in place of the unmanaged <a>. As a result, the links in the *reportlist* are converted for Lightning Experience, while in Classic it remains the same. Here is a sample converted link: `javascript:srcUp('https%3A%2F%2Fns-dev-ed--ns.na30.visual.force.com%2Fapex%2Freportshow%3Fid%3D00O36000002TXfdEAG%26reportName%3DTestingReport%26isdtp%3Dp1');`