# Redirect to new page using Lightning Quick Action

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I am having a quick action with lightning component . The component checks for some condition and redirect to the new page of case object. 
So now when the user click on quick action a modal window is opened which is the default behaviour of quick action lightning component and then the page is redirected to the case new pagge based on certain conditions .

My question here is , is there any possibility to hide this modal pop up from displaying to the user ??  Coz now the user See an empty modal
Pop up and then gets redirected to the new case page .

Answer (score 0):

Refer below Link for redirecting:
[How to open in lightning experience a custom visualforce page that requires parameters?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/128597/how-to-open-in-lightning-experience-a-custom-visualforce-page-that-requires-para)

Hope this helps you.
Diksha

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to close that model but you can do work around on this. You can show spinner on model pop up .